# What is the equivalent of Stata "." in R

Tags: r, stata

I have a `Stata` command which generates the new variable `y` with value `.`

```
gen y=.
```

I want to know whether following is the equivalent command in `R`"

```
y<-NA
```

Comment: can you point to a link for some on-line Stata documentation that says how `.` behaves? Is http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/replacing-missing-values/ helpful?

Comment: Yes, `.` is missing value. Is my `R` command correct?

Comment: I think so. `NA` is certainly the missing-value code in R. I don't know enough about Stata to know whether missing values behave in importantly different ways (I do know that Stata is more flexible for defining multiple kinds of "missingness".)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [this](http://data.princeton.edu/stata/dataManagement.html)

> In Stata the basic missing value for numeric variables is represented by a dot .

In R the missing values are represented by NA.

> Starting with version 8 there are 26 additional missing-value codes
>   denoted by .a to .z. These values are represented internally as very
>   large numbers, so valid_numbers< . < .a < ... < .z.

R haven't such representation of missing data. all missings data are represneted by  `NA`.

> In Stata To check for missing you need to write var >= .

In R, we use `is.na` to check for missing data.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `NA` is logical.  "There are also constants NA_integer_, NA_real_, NA_complex_ and NA_character_".  But most of the time, this distinction can be ignored.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg My point was that there isn't comparison between missing values in R. But the logical fact of NA is a good point. feel free to edit my answer if you think I missed something. I answered this question just to attract more Stata users to R..

Comment: I don't see a need to edit.  The statement "all missing data ..." is technically not correct, but in practice hardly anyone will notice.

Comment: In Stata, the function `missing()` is another way to check for missingness. Also, empty strings `""` are treated as missing. So, the statement that to check for missing you need to check whether a variable is `>= .` is false for strings and false in the sense it is not the only way. However, these details appear unimportant to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer indicates, missing data in an object that can be compared between Stata and R, such as a `data.frame`, will be coded as `NA`. `NULL` is another possibility. Here's an empty matrix:

```
> x = matrix(); x
     [,1]
[1,]   NA
```

It's also possible to have zero-length objects, like an empty string:

```
> x <- ""; x
[1] ""
```

To go back to the useful part of the answer, `NA` and `is.na` are the bits that you want to memorize.